# Url.Action is calling Controller but not return the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Button event in view:

```
var target = '@Url.Action("Login", "Home")';
$.post(target, { UserName: $('#txtEmail').val(), userType: $('#selection').val(),   
Password: $('#txtPassword').val() });
```

and This is controller Action method.This controller is inside the area.
I am Calling this controller from another controller action method.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string Username, string userType, string password)
    {

        HealthCareDataContext dc = null;
        try
        {
            dc = new HealthCareDataContext();
            var usr = (from obj in dc.tblAdmins
                       where obj.Username == Username.Trim()
                       && obj.Status == true
                       select obj).ToList();
            if (usr.Count > 0)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(Username, password);  //Redirect login page.
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Username.Trim(), false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Admin", new { area1 = "Secure", area2 = "Admin" });
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View();
        }
        finally
        {
            dc = null;
        }
    }
```

This Action method is called but it does not return the view. But when i go through the URL manually it return the view.

Where i am doing wrong with calling this action.

Comment: `return RedirectToAction(..)` is pointless (ajax calls stay on the same page so it will be ignored)

Comment: Please put the index action index action Method in the Admin controller

Comment: @Aravindan, Why do you think it isn't? and what has that got to do with it anyway?

Comment: so instead of RedirectToAction(). what i should Use so that it will work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.post(target, { UserName: $('#txtEmail').val(), userType: $('#selection').val(),   
Password: $('#txtPassword').val() }, function(result){
    //Now check your result
});
```

I still have doubt that you have to do this because you are using redirectoaction inside login which will create problem.

If you want to return then try pure ajax call like this.

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: target,
            data: $.param({ UserName: $('#txtEmail').val(), userType: $('#selection').val(),   
Password: $('#txtPassword').val() }) , 
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result);
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert('Error');
            }            
        });
```

Comment: When i Debug the code it goes to Action method of the Admin controller But not return corresponding view .Why its behaving like this?

Comment: RedirectToAction is actually need to handle differently if you want to use ajax. RedirectToAction is like Response.Redirect and it require browser round trip.

Comment: <h2> <i>The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:<br>~/Views/Admin/Index.aspx<br>~/Views/Admin/Index.ascx<br>~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx<br>~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx<br>~/Views/Admin/Index.cshtml<br>~/Views/Admin/Index.vbhtml<br>~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml<br>~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml</i> </h2></span>

Comment: I am getting this exception after editing the code as per your suggestion.